# How can I get a number from an XML file as an integer?

Tags: python, xml

I have been trying to code something on Python recently that looks for a part of an XML file, and prints the result. Very simple, but I need some help with trying to get an integer from the XML.

XML:

```
<totalPages>2</totalPages>
```

Python:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('group.xml')    
pagenum = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('totalPages')
```

When trying to run that code along with the following code I get an error, which is also below:

```
if pagenum > 1:
 ...
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 13, in <module>
pagenum = int(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('totalPages'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NodeList'
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is returning a list. You're comparing `[Node, ...]` to an `int()`. First you need to get the right element for `pagenum` either by using `getElementByTagName` or getting the `[0]` index element. Then you can try your cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `pagenum` is a [NodeList](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#nodelist-objects), so you have to get an item from the list, get a child ([Element](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#element-objects)), and get its data. Using you example:

```
if int(pagenum.item(0).lastChild.data) > 1:
```